# XCode 5.1 UITabbarController tabs issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am using `Storyboard` to create a `UITabbarController`, i have embedded two `UIViewControllers` in it. they are showing connected with it but there no tabs in the `UItabbarController` to customize or even change the name to it… There used to be a tab bar item option in previous XCodes but i can't seem to find it here in `Xcode 5.1`. any help would be great. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the view controllers you can set their title which will change what they appear as when ran. I managed to get the item option to appear once in Xcode 5 but couldn't get it to re appear but the above step will do what you want.